mallocで必要以上のメモリを確保してしまう
起きている現象

ネットワークプログラムを書いているときに、mallocに渡した任意のバイト数と、実際に確保されたバイト数が違うことが起きました。
少し気になったので調べてみましたが、よくわからなかったので質問させていただきます。

サンプルコード
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    size_t size;
    printf("Enter the number of bytes to allocate: ");
    scanf("%zu", &size);

    // メモリを確保
    unsigned char *memory = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);
    if (memory == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("size of malloced memory  : %ld\n", sizeof(memory));

    // メモリをゼロで初期化
    memset(memory, 0, size);

    // メモリにデータを書き込む（例として0から順にバイト値を設定）
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        memory[i] = (unsigned char)i;
    }

    // メモリ内容を表示
    printf("Memory contents:\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%02x ", memory[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    // メモリを解放
    free(memory);

    return 0;
}


実行結果
./test_malloc 
Enter the number of bytes to allocate: 3
size of malloced memory  : 8
Memory contents:
00 01 02 
./test_malloc 
Enter the number of bytes to allocate: 6
size of malloced memory  : 8
Memory contents:
00 01 02 03 04 05 

知りたいこと
配列の長さを知るのはsizeofを使うと習いましたが、きちんと動作しない理由を知りたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

sizeof演算子の使い方の典型的な誤りです。ARR01-C. 配列のサイズを求めるときに sizeof 演算子をポインタに適用しない

@alpha ありがとうございます。　以後気を付けたいです

mallocで取得した領域の実際に使用可能なサイズを取得する関数は標準のCでは用意されていません。しかし、一部の環境では、確保したサイズを取得できる関数が用意されています。
たとえば、ほとんどのLinuxではmalloc_usabel_sizeが使えます。コードに次の行を追加して確認してみてください。
// 先頭に
#include <malloc.h>
// main関数の適当な所で
    printf("usable size of malloced memory  : %zd\n", malloc_usable_size(memory));

実際に実行してみればわかりますが、ほとんどの場合で、必要以上のメモリを確保する、つまり、確保されるサイズは指定したサイズよりも大きくなります。そのサイズまではオーバーランしても安全(他の領域と被らないという意味)であり、reallocでサイズ変更する場合でも、そのサイズ以下であれば、今の領域がそのまま返されるようになります。それがどういう仕組みで、どれぐらい確保されるのかという話になると、実装によって異なってくるので、環境を限定しないと詳しく述べることは難しいです。ただ、一般的に、次のような理由が考えられます。

返すアドレスは必ずmax_align_tの倍数になるため、次の領域を始められるギリギリまで領域を確保しても、全体のメモリ使用の効率は落ちない。
reallocされる場合を想定して、常にギリギリよりも、ある程度マージンを取った方が良い。
経験的に、小さいサイズ単位でとるよりも、一定の大きさを最低限として取った方が効率が良い。
カーネルがメモリを管理する上で、一定のサイズ毎に管理した方がやりやすい。

環境によってはこれ以外の理由もあるかもしれません。より詳しく聞きたい場合は、環境を限定して質問してみると、その環境に詳しい人が答えてくれると思います。

sizeof演算子で配列のサイズを求めることが可能ですが、malloc()で確保した領域は配列ではなく、sizeof演算子で確保したサイズを求めることはできません。この場合、sizeof(memory)はmemoryが指す内容とは関係なく常に「変数memoryが占めるサイズ」、つまりポインタ1つのサイズになります。
malloc()された領域のサイズを後から求める手段は標準Cにはないと思います。malloc()呼び出し時に指定した大きさを記録しておく必要があります。

んでもひとつ

printf("size of malloced memory  : %ld\n", sizeof(memory));


これで確保したサイズを表示しているつもり、なんでしょうけど、これは間違ってます。
sizeof(memory)では、ポインタのサイズしか得られません（なので、常に８）
